# How to pass multiple Map/List/Array from API url to RestController in Java?

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a method which accepts an ArrayList, HashMap and a List as argument and other parameters as well.

```
methodName(String request,
            ArrayList<String> referenceList, 
HashMap<String, String> params,
 Map<String, List<?>> inClause,
boolean isClassicFlatSuggestionBox) throws Exception {};
```

Now I know how to accept normal string parameters and a single Map/List from url.

```
http://localhost:8888/restApi/getSuggestionData/sa/warehouse?number=20,age=4
```

This url returns 2 Path variable String parameter and a map of number and age at Controller like this

```
public ResponseEntity<Collection<?>> getSuggestionList(@PathVariable("request") String request,@PathVariable("reference") String reference, @RequestParam HashMap<String, String> params)
```

But how to pass multiple maps ?
I can't take everything in a single map and then play with it at Controller side.
is there any way to get multiple map/List directly at Controller side ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change this to POST and add payload that contains necessary objects. Then your controller method will look like:

```
    @POST
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<?>> getSuggestionList(
             @PathVariable("request") String request, @PathVariable("reference") String reference, @RequestBody() Payload payload) { }
```

And the Payload class contains the list you want:

```java
public class Payload {

    @XmlElement
    private ArrayList<String> referenceList;

    @XmlElement
    private HashMap<String, String> params;

    // getters and setters here or Lombok :)
}
```

Comment: And how would the API url look like ?

Comment: It depends on how the Path is defined in this controller. Assuming two path variables and path defined as following:

/{request}/{reference}

it will be something like:

localhost:8888/restApi/valueForrequest/valueForReference

Comment: I specifically asked on how to pass multiple maps and you are telling multiple parameters, Passing single map or multiple parameters is not an issue for me. How do I pass multiple maps which can be directly assigned to the respective maps ok controller side ?

Comment: The Payload in my example is a regular Java class what means that you can provide whatever you want there. You can specify one, two or more maps if you wish.

Comment: What if the no. of maps are not fixed ? I want to write a generic code.
This way we have to add a map everytime in the Class